React Mega Menu Spfx Extension
I have already running spfx extension for global navigation using term store, but there are two things i was looking to achieve.

I have implemented the commandBar where it shows the default view from the navigation but I want to change this to Mega Menu. I have come across two SPFX resources which does not adjust to the requirement.
The users has to click on the menu to open the commandBar but i need to ensure when mouse hover the menu should show.

Thanks in advance.
